# My Menu Bar is showing below where I want it.

Tags: html, css

I need some help with my website. The menu bar on my website www.speedsphoto.com is showing on top of the text that I have. Any ideas on how to correct this. The bar with the grey and red should sit just below the black box that has "High Quality photo for residential and commercial properties. Please give me some help.

This is my first time posting on here so if you need more info, please let me know.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: welcome to SO! yes we do need more: could your show yor code (not all of it, just the important part) here and maybe also create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: The page works correctly in Firefox but not in chrome or explorer.

Comment: Post your code or we literally cannot help you.

Comment: I coppied the htom and css to fiddle as you recommended. Hopefully it is correct. http://jsfiddle.net/kTtVE/

Comment: You have two `div` with the same `id` "logo". Change one.

Comment: I did that so I can make the areas above my bar. Not sure how to do it otherwise. I am new to this and made it that way and it seems to do what I want it to. Just trying to fix the menu.

Comment: @user3567099 I noticed from your page that the problem has now been resolved. If my answer below helped you, it'd be great if you could click the checkmark by my answer to accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

By the look of your page, your `<div id="banner"></div>` is forcing down your navbar because it has a fixed height and padding. If you remove this element the navbar will be in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your css

```
#menu ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 935px;
}
```

---

Andy's answer is the more correct way to go, just remove the

```
height: 118px
```

from **#banner{}** in your css